# How to extract a list of lists from a .txt file in python

Tags: python, list

I want to extract a list of lists from a `.txt` file. The data in the `.txt` file is given like this:

```
[[[12,34.2,54.1,46.3,12.2],[9.2,63,23.7,42.6,15.2]],
  [[12,34.2,54.1,46.3,12.2],[9.2,63,23.7,42.6,15.2]],
  [[12,34.2,54.1,46.3,12.2],[9.2,63,23.7,42.6,15.2]]]
```

I want to store it in a list like:

```
listA = [[[12,34.2,54.1,46.3,12.2], [9.2,63,23.7,42.6,15.2]], [[12,34.2,54.1,46.3,12.2], [9.2,63,23.7,42.6,15.2]],[[12,34.2,54.1,46.3,12.2], [9.2,63,23.7,42.6,15.2]]]
```

I tried using the `read()` function, but it reads as a **string**, and I can't seem to find out how to extract what I want.

Comment: This doesn't look like a TXT file, it looks like a JSON file.

Comment: Assuming this is json use the [json](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html) module.

Comment: This file is given to me in the exact same format in a .txt file

Comment: @DimitriosPriovolos check my answer if work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you import a file
https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html

and this is how you parse it
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `literal_eval` method from `ast` package to parse string representation of list:

```
str_list = '''[
  [
    [12,34.2,54.1,46.3,12.2],
    [9.2,63,23.7,42.6,15.2]
  ],
  [
    [12,34.2,54.1,46.3,12.2],
    [9.2,63,23.7,42.6,15.2]
  ],
  [
    [12,34.2,54.1,46.3,12.2],
    [9.2,63,23.7,42.6,15.2]
  ]
]'''

import ast
parsed_list = ast.literal_eval(str_list)
print(parsed_list)
```

Output:

```
[[[12, 34.2, 54.1, 46.3, 12.2], [9.2, 63, 23.7, 42.6, 15.2]], [[12, 34.2, 54.1, 46.3, 12.2], [9.2, 63, 23.7, 42.6, 15.2]], [[12, 34.2, 54.1, 46.3, 12.2], [9.2, 63, 23.7, 42.6, 15.2]]]
```